# Related rates: Time to get airplane on different path

Tags: derivatives

I am stuck on a related rates problem having to do with airplanes traveling on paths at 90 degrees to each other.

The first plane is 75 miles from the point of convergence and is traveling at 450 mph.

The second plane is 100 miles from the point of convergence and is traveling at 600 mph.

I already found the speed at which their distance changes to be -93750 mph by taking the derivative of the pythagorean theorem with respect to t and solving for ds/dt.

But now, it is asking me how much time the controller has to get 1 of the planes on a different path. In other words, it is asking me how long(in hours) until the 2 planes converge at the point of convergence.

Well, for the 2 planes to converge at a single point, rate/distance must be equal for both planes.

So here I go:

$$\frac{450}{75} * \frac{mph}{miles} = \frac{600}{100} * \frac{mph}{miles}$$
$$6hours=6hours$$

But it can't be 6 hours because if plane 1 were to travel for 6 hours, it would end up with a distance traveled of 2700 miles and if plane 2 were to travel for 6 hours, it would end up with a distance traveled of 3600 miles. Those distances are much longer than the distances to the point of convergence.

So how can I figure out the time that the problem is asking for if the simple rule of rate/distance = time doesn't work here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing. But it seems that you should divide the distance by the speed. That is $75/450 = 100/600 = 1/6$ hr. Note that the speed (rate) = distance/time.

Answer (score 0):

The time to convergence is $\frac {\text{distance}}{\text{speed}}$, which in units is $\frac {\text{miles}}{\text {miles/hour}}=\text{hours}$.  If you divide this way, the time to convergence is $\frac 16$ hour.  The speed of convergence is far too high, as if they were flying straight at each other it would be $1050$ miles/hour.  As you didn't show how you got it, I can't say where the problem is.